# How to extract field values from query result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem in extracting data from query result. I have the following method in my model that returns a result of many rows

```
 function method(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_name');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
 }
```

from my controller I call the above function like this

```
     $data['returned_records']= $this->model_name->method();
```

and now I want to display returned_records in table format in a view. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the output in view in tablur form  The code would be something like this:

```
<table border="1">  
          <tbody>  
             <tr>  
                <td>Heading 1</td>  
                <td>Heading 2</td>  
              // add more according to requirement
             </tr>  
             <?php  
             foreach ($returned_records->result() as $row)  
             {  
                ?><tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row->Column_name;?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row->Column_name;?></td>
               // add more according to requirement  
                </tr>  
             <?php }  
             ?>  
          </tbody>  
       </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($returned_records as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $row->column_name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1">  
          <tbody>  
             <tr>  
                <th>Heading 1</th>  
                <th>Heading 2</th>  
             </tr>  
             <?php  
             foreach ($returned_records as $row)  
             {  
                ?><tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row->Column_name1;?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row->Column_name2;?></td>  
                </tr>  
             <?php }  
             ?>  
          </tbody>  
       </table>
```

as you have already returned as "query->result()" no need write $returned_records->result() again..!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to print data in table format in view file.

```
<table>
   <th>Title</th>
    <?php foreach($returned_records as $result){
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $result->title;?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php 
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller function pass $data like the below code:

```
$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

In your view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($returned_records as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row->column_name ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```